# Decode from base64 to decimal character codes

Tags: perl, base64

I've been searching through Google but can't seem to figure out how this string has been decoded.

Decode from base64 to decimal characters

For example,

```
CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg => 9 45 180 82 233 134 21 164 166 209 5 217 231 129 192 14
```

I used many online converters. If possible I would like to get the same result in Perl.

I already used [`MIME::Base64`](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME::Base64) but I get a string instead of a list of numbers.

How are the characters being decoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result from [`MIME::Base64`](https://metacpan.org/module/MIME::Base64) is a string, whereas you have a list of character codes.

This program uses `split` to separate the decoded string into characters, and `ord` to extract the character code of each. Printing the resultant array shows the values to be the same as the list that you show in your question

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use MIME::Base64;

my $str = 'CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg';

my @chars = split //, decode_base64 $str;
my @codes = map ord, @chars;
print "@codes\n";
```

**output**

```
9 45 180 82 233 134 21 164 166 209 5 217 231 129 192 14
```

To generate the original base 64-encoded string, you can write this

```
print encode_base64(join '', map chr, @codes), "\n";
```

**output**

```
CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg==
```

The trailing equals `=` signs are padding that is inserted to round the encoded string to a multiple of three characters. They have no impact on the meaning of the encoded data and you may remove them if you wish.

Comment: thank u verry much for this information and the quick response @borodin

Comment: Ok one more question @Borodin it is offcourse also possible to do this in reverse from numbers to the string? since its split the chars i cannot simple change the decode_base64 to encode_base64 that doenst reverse the outcome. Hope on your answer again.

Comment: `my @chars = unpack 'C*', decode_base64 $str;` and `my $str = encode_base64 pack 'C*', @chars;`

Comment: @ikegami thanks for the response but i cant seem to get it working? i edited the things you said.

Comment: Ok anybody here on stackoverflow that could help me with the reversed script for this?? I cant get it working with the codes from @ikegami, all help appreciated ;)

Comment: huh? The first snippet I gave does the same as Borodin's. The second snippet I gave does the inverse function. I don't know what else anyone could possibly give

Comment: ok @ikegami i understand now what u mean i thought i didnt look good sorry i see it decode and encode 2 different things. I putted that in the same script. But i still cant figure it out:( So if i would like to have the output as input and and the my $str as output could you please show me the script because i can not get that? Sorry for bothering you with this.

Comment: That is the entire script. Well, `use MIME::Base64; my $str = encode_base64 pack 'C*', ...list of chars...;` is the entire script. No idea what else you want???

Comment: ok i understand but there is no output like CS20UumGFaSm0QXZ54HADg when using 9 45 180 82 233 134 21 164 166 209 5 217 231 129 192 14 as input :(